# Proving an implication from one necessary and sufficient criteria for a set to be Lebesgue measurable to another.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

This is a part of [Exercise 1.2.7 in page 34](http://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/measure-book1.pdf) I can't seem to work out.

Let $E\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ and $m^*(E)$ denote the Lebesgue outer measure of $E$. Consider,

$(iii)$ For every $\varepsilon>0$, one can find an open set $U$ such that $m^*(U\Delta E)\leq \varepsilon.$

$(iv)$ For every $\varepsilon>0$, one can find a closed set F contained in E with $m^*(E\backslash F)\leq \varepsilon$.

Show that $(iii)\Rightarrow (iv)$.

Can anyone provide any hints? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I remember this exercise. Here are the equivalences I used in solving this question:

(i)$\iff$(ii) is clear by definition. Then (ii)$\implies$(iii), (ii)$\implies$(iv), (iv)$\implies$(v), (iii)$\implies$(vi), (v)$\implies$(vi), and finally (vi)$\implies$(ii). Tao is tricky in that, in many of these TFAE-type questions, it is most expedient to look for a non-sequential path of implications.

If you would like more help with these implications, please let me know.

EDIT: (ii)$\implies$(iv) hint.

By Lemma 1.3.13(v), if $E$ is Lebesgue measurable, so is $E^c$. Thus there exists an open set $U$ such that $m^*(U\setminus E^c)<\varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon>0$. Can we say something about $U^c$?

Comment: Thanks - might do, gonna give it another shot with that sequence first.

Comment: Yeah, if you could give me a hint to prove $(ii)\Rightarrow (iv)$ that would be great. I can approximate open sets with closed by expressing the open set as a countable union of closed boxes (using the dyadic cubes) and then truncating the union. However, I'm struggling to make the jump from a set that contains $E$ to one that is contained in $E$.

Comment: Added the hint above.

Comment: Glad to hear it.